# Postgresql function lock error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a trigger that updates a cache table.
The function executed by the trigger makes two operation: deletes the old cache row and adds a new cache row based on the id with a total

cache table columns: id | total

Because of the high level of server activity I believe that two paralles calls on the function will generate the following situation:

```
Delete 1 
Delete 2 
Insert 1
Insert 2 ( this will crash because of the primary key )
```

Is there any way I can prevent this ? Shouldn't the transaction prevent this ( the implied transaction in a postgresql function )

Answer (score 2):

you can use a advisory locks. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-admin.html

```
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(old.id);
  DELETE FROM cache WHERE some_id = old.id;
  INSERT INTO cache SELECT ...;
  PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(old.id);
  RETURN old.id;
END;
$$ ...
```

Pavel

Comment: How about pg_try_advisory_lock_shared ?, also are they safe ? will the second job 'wait' until the first one is finished ?

Comment: You can use a shared lock only when you will only read cache - but if you use a repeated read, then you don't need a lock for reading